# how do i retrieve the text which is under div tag in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I do have to fetch all 21 values and print it on console which are under div tag.  When i am writing path //div[@class='grid']/div/div[1], its giving me 21 div tags(elements) as a result and each of div tag contains anchor tag which having some text and that text want to print on my console.

Here is the code:

//div[@class='grid-canvas']/div/div[1]  --Giving 21 elements.
And when i expand this div tag, it's like as below shown..

Which contains  tag.
  Manager


 Which contains  tag.
 Employee

I want to print on console the text of  all 21 elements, such as Manager, Employee and so on. 
Please anyone can help me out?. Thanks!!

Comment: please provide DOM structure or site

Comment: <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l0 r0" xpath="1">
Which contains <a> tag.
<a href="javascript:void(0)" style=" ", text-decoration:none, color""; onClick" "> Manager
</div>
<div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l0 r0" xpath="2">
Which contains <a> tag.
<a href="javascript:void(0)" style=" ", text-decoration:none, color""; onClick" "> Employee
</div>
I wanted to print text Employee, Manager and so from all 21 div tag.

Comment: would be great if you provide site or consolidated DOM

Comment: And please add it to your question and not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your explaination please find below xpath where I am considering div[1]= `div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l0 r0" xpath="1"`

```
 (//div[@class='grid-canvas']/div/div[*])[1]/a
```

and for Employee div[2]=`div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l0 r0" xpath="2"`

```
 (//div[@class='grid-canvas']/div/div[*])[2]/a
```

Comment: Thanks, but my requirement is to put it in too loop, individually it's printing,

Comment: Yes, i will but please give me the solution for printing all text one after another. That's my requirement. If i will hit up, i won't get answer from others as well. Is it so?

Comment: In above question i mentioned, wanted to print all 21 names.

Comment: Please check above answer from your end also accept and hit upvote  button

Comment: Yes, for(WebElement element : listOfDivs)
{
    System.out.println(element.getText());
} Has displayed my all names. Thanks for your help.